# when do we need divs and spans to be clickable, why wouldn't we rather use a button?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

It is my understanding that anything that is clickable on a web page must be a link or a button. If on click, you want to take the user to a different page or a new context, you should use a link, If you are triggering an action while staying on the same page, you should use a button.

Does this understanding exclude any use cases?

I am trying to understand when is it all right to use div or span with click handlers? why wouldn't you rather use a button (and style it properly).

Why does the role="button" exist (apart from the toggle button use case, may be), if we may never need to use it on div or span or other elements, because we could instead use a button and style it properly? What exactly are the use cases where this is not possible?

EDIT: keeping the question closed as is, but adding some more findings here

- role="button" is anyway useful outside of HTML, as an aria role
- div without the button semantics can be used to enhance some functionality only for mouse users, if the functionality has already been exposed in some other way for the keyboard and screenreader users. This usage, in turn, also validates that not every thing that is interactive needs to be a button or a link

Comment: When styling unique toggles or switches, one method is to wrap a hidden radio/checkbox inside a span, label or div, and style that element and whatever is inside it (excluding the hidden control). You can't use a button because it's not valid HTML.

Comment: That's a valid point, but then again, why is some markup that's invalid inside a button tag, is valid inside role="button"?

Comment: Roles are just there for accesibility purposes, to tell the screen reader to treat that as a button, or rather, to let it know that element is supposed to be a button. You still need to emulate what a native button does on screen readers, like tabbing, pressing enter on it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Natively, `div` and `span` elements aren't keyboard focusable and weren't meant to respond to mouse clicks or keyboard input. However, when people started creating [rich Internet applications (RIAs) or rich web applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_web_application), they needed user interface components that HTML did not provide natively. Examples include(d) sliders, rich text editors, spreadsheets (see Google Sheets) and drag-and-drop functionality. These allowed user interfaces and interaction types that people were familiar with on the desktop but that were not provided natively by existing HTML elements.

Developers started building such user interface components using the available HTML elements (`div` and `span` were used a lot because they don't have any specific native "semantics"), JavaScript and CSS. These UI components responded to mouse input in the way that sighted users expected, but were meaningless to blind users, who cannot use a mouse and need to rely on the UI semantics conveyed by a screen reader.

This lack of semantics for those new components required a type of markup that would convey a component's role (e.g. `gridcell`, `slider`, `tabpanel` or `menubar`), state (e.g. `aria-checked` or `aria-disabled` for certain controls) and properties (e.g. min and max values for a slider).

Button and link elements don't fit all of the above use cases, which is why `div` and `span` elements were often used to create UI components.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of useful information. I get the perspective, that when creating custom UI elements, it might be ok to use on click on divs and spans. I still have a few doubts though, would divs and spans used in these UI elements ever require a functionality which do not require a keyboard listener and only click handler? in case they do, wouldn't it be the same functionality as a button?

Comment: Or may be, this is to suggest that even though the divs and spans have click and keyboard listeners, they do not necessarily need to have role="button" as they can some other role. In this case, it is fine to start with a non semantic element and assign a role to it, instead of choosing a button and changing its role.

Comment: The trouble is, if such an element only has a click handler and no keyboard listener, how is a keyboard user (blind or with a motor impairment) going to be able to use it? Making such an element keyboard focusable is easy (just use the `tabindex` attribute), but if no keyboard use is possible, the component will fail WCAG.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was suggesting, if you only use click handler, you are not making it accessible, and if you are using both click and key listeners, why not use a button instead?

Comment: If a native HTML element is available, it is always preferable to use that element. So using a `button` element is better than a `span` with the button role. However, for a very long time, CSS styling for button elements had poor support in browsers, so users and frameworks resorted to other elements.

Answer (score 2):

### use case for a clickable div

One use case is to make a `div` container clickable while there is already an interactive element inside like a button or a link.

This will improve mouse navigation to make a whole area clickable while only the link text would be focusable with the keyboard.

But this div must have no role as you can not have an interactive element inside another interactive element.

### use case for `button` role

the only valid use case would be an already activable element where we would want to override the default native role.

This definition seems to match the [`<input type="checkbox" />`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-input-checkbox) element [used with the `aria-pressed` attribute](https://github.com/w3c/html-aria/issues/6)

Comment: I didn't get it immediately after your comment, but after some time, now I get one of the use cases for the clickable div, without button semantics. if you have a scenario, where you need to enhance the experience for a mouse user, while the same functionality is already exposed to the keyboard user / screenreader user by other means, it makes sense to just add onClick to the div without the button semantics.